# Can jQuery detect a specific URL and perform a function based off that URL?

Tags: jquery

I have a site I'm working on.  I need to be able to perform a specific function if the URL matches a specific URL.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

If the URL matches this URL:

http://www.example.com/EIFS-items/search.php?l2=3,15,25

then I want to have jQuery add a class of "show" to the div with the class of "content" below.

Is this possible?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
.content {
display: none;
}
.show {
display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div><!-- end .content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check against document.location once the page is loaded and apply the CSS that way i would presume

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/EIFS-items/search.php?l2=3,15,25";
$(function(){
  if (location.href==url){
    $('.content').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: sweet...that did the trick...thanks so much!  I just changed the jQuery to have ".content" instead of "#content".  thnx again!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for the [`location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location), which contains information about the URL of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Probably will be better to use the querystring `location.search` than `location.href`. This would cover subdomains/protocol changes.

```
if(location.search == "?l2=3,15,25")
    $('.content').addClass('show');
```