# How To Have A Link Only Appear In Certain Pages

Tags: html, css

I would like a link to appear everywhere on the blog apart from the homepage.

However I only want the link to not work on the homepage, I still want the word `YOUR PAGE` there, just without a link.

```
<center>
    <div id='customheader'>
       <a href='http://www.yourpage.com/'>YOUR PAGE</a>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: What is the server side application that you are using? You need to use a scripting language. Either on  browser (JavaScript) or on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can jQuery detect a specific URL and perform a function based off that URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619601/can-jquery-detect-a-specific-url-and-perform-a-function-based-off-that-url)

Comment: plenty of answers to this already on stackoverflow, also the center tag is depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript:

```
if (document.URL == 'http://www.yourpage.com/') {
    document.getElementById('customheader').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 'Your page');
} else {
    document.getElementById('customheader').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<a href="http://www.yourpage.com">Your page</a>');  
}
```

Using PHP:

```
<div id='customheader'>
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php") {
    echo "YOUR PAGE";
  } else {
    echo "<a href='http://www.yourpage.com/'>YOUR PAGE</a>";
  }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    body #customheader a[href]:after { content: ''; }
</style>
```

But you'd need to make it so that only appears on the home page. It also won't work on older browsers.